# Nunjucks Include Path with Variable from Data in a Macro

Tags: variables, macros, gulp, include, nunjucks

Hoping somebody can provide a little insight into an issue I'm having with Nunjucks. Here's the scenario...

I'm trying to produce a single page that loads some data and an HTML file from a JSON Data file. I'm using a Macro to loop through the Data JSON. Within the macro I can say:

```
templates/elements/{{ title | lower | replace(" ", "-") }}.html
```

And it will output a relative URL to the HTML snippet I want - `title` comes from the JSON.

When I try to do the same thing as an include, I get parsing errors in Gulp.

```
{% include "../elements/" + {{ title | lower | replace(" ", "-") }} + ".njk" %}
```

My understanding is that this is an order of operations thing with Nunjucks. So how do I get around this? I need to load the HTML snippet for several files and it doesn't make sense to store it in the Data JSON.

Hopefully that makes sense!

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Try `{% include "../elements/" + (title | lower | replace(" ", "-")) + ".njk" %}`